# Packing a GL_RGB from three separate buffers?

Tags: opengl, texture

I'm decoding an `.mp4` to use as a texture on a tristrip. It's easy enough to use an unsigned byte array of RGB triplets to create this texture, but frames come out of an `.mp4` as three separate buffers. One for each channel. In other words, instead of having `uint8_t * buf = {RGBRGBRGBRGB.....}`, I have `uint8_t * r_buf = {RRRRR....}; uint8_t * g_buf = {GGGGG....}; uint8_t * b_buf = {BBBBBB....};` Can I pack all of this into one texture so my fragment shader just treats it the same as it did the current texture? I don't have any great objection to having three separate 1-channel textures that I mix in the shader, but that'll ugly up my shader code a bit.

Comment: "*RGB triplets*" You really don't want to do that. It'd be best to use four channels, even if the alpha channel is 1. Your upload times to the GPU will improve.

Comment: You're right, I don't want to do that, but I don't have a choice since that's how the data comes to me from the ffmpeg library. The problem turned out to be a helluva lot more complicated than I realized - ffmpeg is giving me YUV streams in 8:4:4 grouping instead of RGB. However, other formats I deal with will still present the problem posed in the question, so I'll leave it up.

Comment: Why would you expect that RGBA would be faster than RGB? It's 33% more data to have to transfer to the graphics hardware every frame (the video in question is 1920x1080 @ 30fps, so adding an alpha channel increases the data transfer demand by 60 million bytes per second.

Comment: "*Why would you expect that RGBA would be faster than RGB?*" Because GPUs generally cannot do misaligned reads. So they don't *have* RGB formats; they're a fiction created by the API. If you upload from RGB data, the driver will internally have to copy each pixel of data to a 4-channel format, then DMA that into GPU memory. That's slower than you simply preparing the data correctly ahead of time.